# Tomcat Cors + Oracle ORDS is blocking my angular request

Tags: angular, oracle, cors, tomcat9, oracle-ords

I have an angular client, which should get data from an Oracle Rest Data Service. The ORDS runs inside a tomcat, which is handling the authentication.

If I do the request with curl it works. I have a c# webapi and I wrote a controller to get the data from ORDS => also Works.
So my angular client recieves data from c# webapi => ORDS but not from ORDS directly.

```
login(username, password) {
    let b64 = btoa(username + ':' + password);
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', b64);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + b64);
    return this.http.get<any>(`URL to ORDS`, {headers} ).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
  }
```

my tomcat web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:4200/</param-value>
      </init-param> 
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param> 
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param> 
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors..support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param> 
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors..preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
      </init-param> 
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

At the moment the server returns

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL to ORDS' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ORDS package API to set a list of allowed origins

```
BEGIN
       ORDS.SET_MODULE_ORIGINS_ALLOWED(
              P_MODULE_NAME       => 'test',
              P_ORIGINS_ALLOWED   => 'www.thatjeffsmith.com'
       );
END;
/
```

When I make my request to my test module with the proper Origin header, my response indicates that's it's been allowed

[image]

If my request header indicates I'm coming from somewhere not allowed...

[image]

It can be this simple, but often there's a lot more going on. It's easiest to debug when we get our hands on a [HAR](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting#h_2598b2df-ca9f-49bc-8166-054c9e5e665a) (a log of network requests)

Comment: I tried your solution, but it's still not working. Here a link to my .har file: https://cs.myasp.eu/portal/s/155301230701720273631.har

Comment: @KnApP993 that log only has a 401 on a HEAD request, don't see any cors issues or ords resources...

Comment: I have fixed my issue so far. If I start chrome with --disable-web-security the cors issue disappear. What does that mean for my production environment? Is it possible to change that behavior on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has provided a config param to avoid CORS issue in ORDS apps.
Use it in defaults.xml that is created under config directory.

```
<entry key="security.externalSessionTrustedOrigins">http://www.example.com</entry>
```

But, this is supported from ORDS 20.4 versions. For below versions, CORS to be handled from clients.